# verify the dimension theorem for this function

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

i'm having trouble answering this question.

$T:M_{2x3}(F) \mapsto M_{2x2}(F), T
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ = $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2a_{11}-a_{12} & a_{13} + 2a_{12} \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$

for the range, i have $R(T)=$$
    \{\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b\\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}|a,b \in R\}
$ and the basis of $R(T)$ is $
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$, so $dim(R(T)) = rank(T)=2$

but i am stuck on calculating nullity. this is my work so far.

i believe the null space $N(T)$ is $
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    a & b & c \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$ where $a,b,c \in R$. i believe this implies a basis of three elements, $
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$, $
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$, $
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$, so $rank(T)=dim(N(T))=3$, but the answer in the back of the book says it's 4.

where have i gone wrong here? or may it be the case that there's an error in the book?

thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Since you’re verifying the “dimension theorem,” what does it say about what the nullity should be?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the $a_2$ in the first entry is supposed to be $a_{12}$, you get an additional independent solution if you solve $2a_{11} - a_{12} = 0$ and $a_{13} + 2a_{12} = 0$, e.g. $a_{11} = 1$, $a_{12} = 2$, $a_{13} = -4$.

Comment: yes, it is supposed to be $a_{12}$. thank you for spotting that!